# Boost::Python: Passing custom arguments to gcc when building python-extension

Tags: linux, boost, boost-python, boost-build, bjam

I need to pass `-Wl,-rpath,\$$ORIGIN/lib/` to g++'s linker ([reason](http://blog.linuxgamepublishing.com/2009/02/08/our-new-way-to-meet-the-lgpl/)). Is there a way to pass this argument in Jamroot file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ivan Vucica already described how to do it by modifying the toolset](https://stackoverflow.com/users/39974/ivan-vucica).  Another option is to add it to the properties of the project.  At the top of your Jamroot, add the following rule (or modify a pre-existing `project` rule).

```
project
  : requirements
      <toolset>gcc:<linkflags>"-Wl,-rpath,\\$ORIGIN/lib"
  ;
```

This will only affect gcc on this project, and works even if the current `using gcc ;` command is called from outside Jamroot (as in Ubuntu's default configuration).

There might be a better way by somehow modifying the python-for-extensions alias that Boost.Build links against when calling python-extension, but I'm not sure how to do it, or even if it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

To modify linkflags, use approximately:

```
using gcc : : : <linkflags>"-Wl,-rpath,\\$ORIGIN/lb" ;
```

Source: [RTM](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/overview/configuration.html)